# XCode/Swift: how to manage constraints of two overlapping imageviews

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, constraints, draggable

In my app I would like to manage a draggable pin, which is an UIImageView, upon a larger UIImageView. This is a screenshot in my storyboard:

[image]

The problem is I am not able to manage constraints: I would like the pin image to be draggable only inside the large UIImageView below. 
Do you have any ideas about how writing those constraints?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: answer**

No constraint is needed in `Main.storyboard` and overall it is necessary to implement each pin as a subclass of `UIImageView` with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Here's the class into which I coded the dimensions the pin is allowed to move on:

```
import UIKit

class PinImageView: UIImageView {

var lastLocation:CGPoint?
var panRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer?

init(imageIcon: UIImage?, location:CGPoint) {
    super.init(image: imageIcon)
    self.lastLocation = location
    self.panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"detectPan:")
    self.center = location
    self.gestureRecognizers = [panRecognizer!]
    self.frame = CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 20.0, height: 30.0)
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func detectPan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation  = recognizer.translationInView(self.superview!)
    let newLocation = CGPointMake(lastLocation!.x + translation.x, lastLocation!.y + translation.y)

    if ((newLocation.x >= 26 && newLocation.x <= 292) && (newLocation.y >= 71 && newLocation.y <= 461)){
        self.center = CGPointMake(newLocation.x, newLocation.y)
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    // Promote the touched view
    self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)

    // Remember original location
    lastLocation = self.center
}

}
```